# GPL-compatible toast notifications library for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, library, c#, notification

I am developing a GNU-GPLv3-licensed C# Windows app.
I want to show non-invasive notifications that disappear after a few seconds.
Something like this:

[image: Mac OS X toast notifications]

Is there a GPL-compatible C# library to show such notifications?

Requirements:

- GPL-compatible
- Works on Windows Vista SP2 and above
- Some kind of way for the user to be able to make a particular toast not disappear, for instance to take time to read it carefully.
- If several notifications come within a short time, they stack so that each notifications is visible a few seconds

If no library is needed and there is a native way to do this, it would be even better.

[Windows Toast Notifications](https://github.com/noxad/windows-toast-notifications) sounds good but it is not GPL-compatible.

Comment: While not as flexible, if your application has a system tray icon, it can produce tooltip notifications using that natively.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: Thanks! Would that fit the 3rd requirement?

Comment: If the user hovers their mouse over the notification, it will persist until they move their mouse away or click the `[X]` in the corner.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: Sorry I added a 4th requirement, that if 2 notifications come at the same time, both should be visible.